# How can i make different words in a tableviewcell with different font

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a table view. in that one row is having different lines
for that i wrote code like this:

```
cell.textLabel.text=@"Hi this is PRASAD";
```

here i want only "PRASAD" with different font & must be in BOLD.

what logic i have to implement in textlabel?

Comment: You can use two labels and change the font style as per your likings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. A `UILabel` cannot have multiple font characteristics. The only option is to make a custom view for the cell that is either a webview or multiple labels.

Answer (score 1):

Use NSAttributedString for holding text and CoreText for rendering.
It is fast & it works but surely not as easy as UILable :)

Look at the core text sample code by Apple

There is also a gitHub project "NSAttributedString + HTML" look it up.
There are a lot of CoreText projects as well on gitHub.